# How to make when i click JButton to make it doubling output. For ex i click jButton once, but i want to output 2

Tags: java, swing, button, cookies, double

I'm trying to make cookie clicker game and i'm at point where i want to program upgrades, for ex: when i buy first upgrade i want if i click once to get 2 cookies, before upgrade it was if i click once i get only 1 cookie. I'm not sure how to code that and also in the future i want to code even more upgrades. What i'm asking to someone help me to make peace of code that can be used to make clicking upgrades.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.*;

public class JavaApplication13 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DBP prozor = new DBP();
        prozor.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        prozor.setVisible(true);
    }  
}

class DBP extends JFrame {
    private JLabel oznaka;

    public DBP() {
        setTitle("Cookie Clicker");
        setSize(500, 150);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 30, 20));

        oznaka = new JLabel("No points!");
        add(oznaka);
        JButton dugme = new JButton("Click");
        add(dugme);

        JButton upgrade = new JButton("Buy upgrade!");
        add(upgrade);
        upgrade.setVisible(false);

        dugme.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            private int brojac;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                brojac++;
                oznaka.setText("Points " + brojac);
                if (brojac == 5) {
                    upgrade.setVisible(true);  
                }   
            }
        });

        upgrade.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                upgrade.setVisible(false);
                System.out.println("SA");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you simply `brojac = brojac + 2;`?

Comment: @GeorgeZ.Where exactly to put it, because, i can't put that under upgrade.addActionListener and public void actionPerformed, if i do that i got a error message cannot find symbol...

Comment: Instead of `brojac++;`.

Comment: @GeorgeZ.Yeah, but problem is that now immediately start to count +2, ex: 2, 4 ,6... but i don't want that, i want at start to count 1, 2, 3, 4 and when i'm on 5 i got second button "upgrade" and i want only if i click that button to add everytime when i click "Click" count +2;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do it, is to keep a `boolean` value if the user has clicked the `upgrade` button. If he did, increase "cookies" one more time.

```
public class JavaApplication13 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // All swing applications must run on their own thread.
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            DBP prozor = new DBP();
            prozor.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            prozor.setVisible(true);
        });

    }

}

class DBP extends JFrame {
    private JLabel oznaka;
    private boolean upgraded; //whether user upgraded

    public DBP() {
        setTitle("Cookie Clicker");
        setSize(500, 150);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 30, 20));

        oznaka = new JLabel("No points!");
        add(oznaka);
        JButton dugme = new JButton("Click");
        add(dugme);

        JButton upgrade = new JButton("Buy upgrade!");
        add(upgrade);
        upgrade.setVisible(false);

        dugme.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            private int brojac;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                brojac++;
                if (upgraded)
                    brojac++;
                oznaka.setText("Points " + brojac);
                if (brojac == 5) {
                    upgrade.setVisible(true);

                }

            }
        });

        upgrade.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                upgrade.setVisible(false);
                upgraded = true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: @Mato Take some time and read [what should i do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Yeah, i want to vote up your help, but i can't do it. When i try it says that i can't up vote someone respond because my rating is bellow 15 points...